# Is cordova-plugin-background-mode Accepted by iOS AppStore and Android PlayStore?

Tags: cordova, google-play, app-store, cordova-plugins, background-process

The [cordova-plugin-background-mode](https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode) Github page has this warning about app store compliance:

```
Store Compliance

Infinite background tasks are not official supported on most mobile operation systems and     
thus not compliant with public store vendors. A successful submssion isn't garanteed.
```

Has anyone successfully submitted it?

Has anyone used this plugin and had difficulty submitting it to the iOS or Android stores?

Are there specific scenarios which get rejected? Is it when its truly an infinite background task that never stops or are there other scenarios which get rejected as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep. Just got rejected today. First they rejected the metadata because it appeared in the configuration. Tried explaining myself to their review board as to why we need this and they just rejected the binary outright. So ... pfff there goes my inactivity lockout on iOS. Digging for a new solution...

Android accepted no problem ...

Comment: Sorry to hear that. How often it would run? Some of the discussion about that I had seen suggested that rejections were specific to processes that would potentially run indefinitely in the background and drain the battery but it sounds like from what you said they straight up just don't like it whatever the use.

Comment: They asked "how does your app use background audio", I explained that the plugin uses it to achieve background processing and that we need it to time the user while tabbed out of the app, and then lock the app after some time of inactivity. They didn't seem interested in any more info and just rejected the binary...

Comment: Any solution on this?

Comment: @MarioKurzweil not sure, this is the latest doc for Ionic background mode https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-mode, I would first investigate any open issues on https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode about this issue